Tantric text books about mahavidyas
The mahavidya deities are associated with vamachara method of worship which not well informed in the open network which the public uses. I know that for maa Tara I must look up to the brihat Nila tantra, Tara Rahasya, for maa Kamakhya , the kalika puran etc. what are some of the core text books , be it in any vernacular language or translations, to read about maa Kali, Chinnamasta , dhumavati, bagalamukhi, matangi, Bhuvaneswari , shodasi , Bhairavi and kamalatmika ?

In Bengali there are some good books ..like Dasa Mahavidya Tattva Rahasyam etc. But it should be taken care of that Mahavidya worship should not be initiated just by reading books.Guru's guidance is a must in this regard.
